# How to use a vue 2 dependency that uses Vue.extend() in a nuxt 3 app?

Tags: node.js, npm, vuejs2, vuejs3, nuxt3

I am working on a nuxt 3 application and in this repo I am npm installing a private package that uses vue 2 under the hood. I install this package and create a plugin and register it in the nuxt.config.ts file inside the `plugins:[]` array properly. I definitely installed the package with npm but when I run the nuxt 3 app I see this error in the browser:

```
500
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'extend')

at Module.fb15 (./node_modules/generic-library/dist/generic.common.js:20059:140)
at __webpack_require__ (./node_modules/generic-library/dist/generic.common.js:21:30)
at ./node_modules/generic-library/dist/generic.common.js:85:18
at Object. (./node_modules/generic-library/dist/generic.common.js:88:10)
at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1165:14)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1219:10)
at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1043:32)
at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:878:12)
at ModuleWrap. (node:internal/modules/esm/translators:169:29)
at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:193:25)
```

Found at generic.commom.js @20059 as an example of the underlying node_modules source code...

```
/* harmony default export */ var generic_horizontal_pickervue_type_script_lang_ts_ = (external_commonjs_vue_commonjs2_vue_root_Vue_default.a.extend({
  name: 'GenericHorizontalPicker',
  components: {
    SomeComponent: some_component
  },
  model: {
    prop: 'modelValue',
    event: 'select'
  },

...
```

I think the issue is that the installed npm package creates their vue components using this type of syntax:

```
export default Vue.extend({
  name: 'MyGenericComponent',
 })
```

the plugin

```
import GenericLibrary from "generic-library";

export default defineNuxtPlugin(() => {
  return {
    provide: GenericLibrary
  };
});
```

This the `extend()` function is causing the 500 error.

Is it possible to install and use apps that are vue2 + use vue.extend() as an npm package inside of a nuxt 3 application? Or will the differences in vue versions be a permanent issue that cannot be worked around? Could it be because nuxt 3 uses vite and the npm package is using webpack? Thanks.

Using node v16 and npm v8.19.3.